# Excel macro to change a cell value and disable a column based on another cell value

Tags: vba, excel

If cell 1 has value A1 then cell 2 should have value B1 and column H should be disabled.

If cell 1 has value A2 then cell 2 should have value B2 and column H should NOT be disabled.

Here is the code, but somehow it doesn't work for value "A1".

```
Private Function func1(pVal as String) as String
If pVal = "A1"
func1="B1"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H1:h100").Locked=True
ElseIF pVal="A2"
func1="B2"
EndIF
End func1
```

When user selects "A1" in call 1, I get an error #value in cell 2.

Comment: can you define `cell 1` and `cell 2`? is `func1` supposed to be a UDF?

Answer (score 0):

A function used in a worksheet cell can only return a value, not lock or unlock anything.  The best yo can do without a **sub** is :

```
Public Function func1(pVal As String) As String
    func1 = "What Ever"
    If pVal = "A1" Then
        func1 = "B1"
    Else
        If pVal = "A2" Then
            func1 = "B2"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```